# Azure website activity issues

Tags: azure

Morning all.

We have a problem with one of our websites on azure.
It has been running fine but then last night at midnight (exactly midnight) the site started getting HTTP errors and all things went up (requests, cpu time, etc) which is really weird. It is only happening to this site out of the many we have.

I am not sure what is causing it; I am thinking ddos attacks, but I can think of no reason why anyone would target our site.

Here is a screenshot of the monitor board.

[image]

Has anyone had experiences like this before? Or may know what is causing it?

Comment: A first check: do the http logs confirm the data you are seeing on the portal?

Comment: Given the info you provided (basically just a view of perf counters), this looks to be either  either something specific to your app, or potentially related to an Azure service disruption (which would require you to look at the Azure [status](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/#history) page). I don't see this as an issue that's solvable on StackOverflow, given that it's not a programming issue.

Comment: aye, azure support links stack overflow as a place to post questions. I have checked the status page and although a lot of things seemed to have problems yesterday nothing in my region seems to have been affected. Not sure where to go for support on this....seems odd to me that this started happening last night at exactly midnight....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very handy tool via the Kudu console for Azure Websites that can help you in figuring out what may be going on with your site. To access it type in a url like this, https://mywebsite.scm.azurewebsites.net/support

You can see live stats for your site. There is also an Analyze tab that you can use to help diagnose issues with your site. Click the Diagnose button and give the tool some time to collect and analyze your logs.

hope that helps.
Mark